# How to get a single column from a Doctrine Array Collection?

Tags: php, symfony, collections, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

i have a entity called "AreasProfesionales"

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\InverseJoinColumn;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\OrderFilter;
use App\Repository\AreasProfesionalesRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AreasProfesionalesRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['Codigo'], message: 'Ya existe un area profesional registrada con ese mismo código')]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['Denominacion' => 'partial', 'Codigo' => 'partial', 'familiasProfesionales'=> 'exact'])]
#[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, properties: ['id'], arguments: ['orderParameterName' => 'order'])]
#[ApiResource(paginationEnabled: false,formats: ['json' => ['application/json']],
normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write']])]

class AreasProfesionales
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['read','write'])]
    #[ApiProperty(writable:true)]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['read','write'])]
    private ?string $Denominacion = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 20, unique:true)]
    #[Groups(['read', 'write'])]
    private ?string $Codigo = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'Familiasprofesionales_areasprofesionales')]
    #[Groups(['read','write'])]
    #[InverseJoinColumn(name: "familias_profesionales_id", referencedColumnName: "id")]
    #[ApiProperty(readableLink: true, writableLink: true)]
    private ?FamiliasProfesionales $familiasProfesionales = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'areasProfesionales', targetEntity: CertificadosProfesionalidad::class)]
    private Collection $Areasprofesionales_certificadosprofesionalidad;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'areasProfesionales', targetEntity: AreasProfesionalesDocentes::class)]
    private Collection $Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesdocentes;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'areasProfesionales', targetEntity: AreasProfesionalesItinerariosFormativos::class)]
    private Collection $Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesitinerariosformativos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Areasprofesionales_certificadosprofesionalidad = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesdocentes = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesitinerariosformativos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDenominacion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Denominacion;
    }

    public function setDenominacion(string $Denominacion): self
    {
        $this->Denominacion = $Denominacion;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodigo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Codigo;
    }

    public function setCodigo(string $Codigo): self
    {
        $this->Codigo = $Codigo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFamiliasProfesionales(): ?FamiliasProfesionales
    {
        return $this->familiasProfesionales;
    }

    public function setFamiliasProfesionales(?FamiliasProfesionales $familiasProfesionales): self
    {
        $this->familiasProfesionales = $familiasProfesionales;

        return $this;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return Collection<int, CertificadosProfesionalidad>
     */
    /*public function getAreasprofesionalesCertificadosprofesionalidad(): Collection
    {
        return $this->Areasprofesionales_certificadosprofesionalidad;
    }

    public function addAreasprofesionalesCertificadosprofesionalidad(CertificadosProfesionalidad $areasprofesionalesCertificadosprofesionalidad): self
    {
        if (!$this->Areasprofesionales_certificadosprofesionalidad->contains($areasprofesionalesCertificadosprofesionalidad)) {
            $this->Areasprofesionales_certificadosprofesionalidad->add($areasprofesionalesCertificadosprofesionalidad);
            $areasprofesionalesCertificadosprofesionalidad->setAreasProfesionales($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAreasprofesionalesCertificadosprofesionalidad(CertificadosProfesionalidad $areasprofesionalesCertificadosprofesionalidad): self
    {
        if ($this->Areasprofesionales_certificadosprofesionalidad->removeElement($areasprofesionalesCertificadosprofesionalidad)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($areasprofesionalesCertificadosprofesionalidad->getAreasProfesionales() === $this) {
                $areasprofesionalesCertificadosprofesionalidad->setAreasProfesionales(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }*/
    
    /**
     * @return Collection<int, AreasProfesionalesDocentes>
     */
    /public function getAreasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesdocentes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesdocentes;
    }

    public function addAreasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesdocente(AreasProfesionalesDocentes $areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesdocente): self
    {
        if (!$this->Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesdocentes->contains($areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesdocente)) {
            $this->Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesdocentes->add($areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesdocente);
            $areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesdocente->setAreasProfesionales($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAreasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesdocente(AreasProfesionalesDocentes $areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesdocente): self
    {
        if ($this->Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesdocentes->removeElement($areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesdocente)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesdocente->getAreasProfesionales() === $this) {
                $areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesdocente->setAreasProfesionales(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }*/

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, AreasProfesionalesItinerariosFormativos>
     */
   public function getAreasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesitinerariosformativos(): Collection
   {
        return $this->Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesitinerariosformativos;
    }

    public function addAreasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesitinerariosformativo(AreasProfesionalesItinerariosFormativos $areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesitinerariosformativo): self
    {
        if (!$this->Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesitinerariosformativos->contains($areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesitinerariosformativo)) {
            $this->Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesitinerariosformativos->add($areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesitinerariosformativo);
            $areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesitinerariosformativo->setAreasProfesionales($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAreasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesitinerariosformativo(AreasProfesionalesItinerariosFormativos $areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesitinerariosformativo): self
    {
        if ($this->Areasprofesionales_areasprofesionalesitinerariosformativos->removeElement($areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesitinerariosformativo)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesitinerariosformativo->getAreasProfesionales() === $this) {
                $areasprofesionalesAreasprofesionalesitinerariosformativo->setAreasProfesionales(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
```

I have another entity called "FamiliasProfesionales"

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\OrderFilter;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use App\Repository\FamiliasProfesionalesRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: FamiliasProfesionalesRepository::class)]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['Denominacion' => 'partial'])]
#[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, properties: ['id', 'Denominacion'], arguments: ['orderParameterName' => 'order'])]
#[ApiResource(paginationEnabled: false,formats: ['json' => ['application/json']],
normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write']])]
class FamiliasProfesionales
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['read','write'])]
    #[ApiProperty(writable:true)]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['read','write'])]
    private ?string $Denominacion = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'familiasProfesionales', targetEntity: AreasProfesionales::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn()]
    private Collection $Familiasprofesionales_areasprofesionales;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Familiasprofesionales_areasprofesionales = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDenominacion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Denominacion;
    }

    public function setDenominacion(string $Denominacion): self
    {
        $this->Denominacion = $Denominacion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, AreasProfesionales>
     */
    public function getFamiliasprofesionalesAreasprofesionales(): Collection
    {
        return $this->Familiasprofesionales_areasprofesionales;
    }

    public function addFamiliasprofesionalesAreasprofesionale(AreasProfesionales $familiasprofesionalesAreasprofesionale): self
    {
        if (!$this->Familiasprofesionales_areasprofesionales->contains($familiasprofesionalesAreasprofesionale)) {
            $this->Familiasprofesionales_areasprofesionales->add($familiasprofesionalesAreasprofesionale);
            $familiasprofesionalesAreasprofesionale->setFamiliasProfesionales($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFamiliasprofesionalesAreasprofesionale(AreasProfesionales $familiasprofesionalesAreasprofesionale): self
    {
        if ($this->Familiasprofesionales_areasprofesionales->removeElement($familiasprofesionalesAreasprofesionale)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($familiasprofesionalesAreasprofesionale->getFamiliasProfesionales() === $this) {
                $familiasprofesionalesAreasprofesionale->setFamiliasProfesionales(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    
}
```

I´m using API PLATFORM in my proyect to show all the operations and services.

[image: API PLATFORM_Post_Method]

Is there a way to get only a single field from the Collection? I want the entity "AreasProfesionales" to only appear, for example, the id from "FamiliasProfesionales"
if I need to create a new professional area in the POST method, I only have to enter the id of the professional family to which it belongs and not have to enter all the other data, however, it returns all its fields.Thank you in advance.

I have been trying using the read and write methods of API Platform, but I don't get the result I want, I think the problem is that Api Platform works with IRI and not with id (but i need work with this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can :

```
<?php
// api/src/Entity/Book.php
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ApiResource(normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['book']])]
class Book
{
    #[Groups('book')]
    public $name;

    #[Groups('book')]
    public $author;

    // ...
}
```

you can follow this documentation : https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/

Regards,